# Parashas Eikev: The Consolation of Exile

Tags: sources-mekorot, commentaries, chabad, ekev

The Lubavitcher Rebbe [is quoted](https://www.chabad.org/therebbe/article_cdo/aid/92403/jewish/Eikev-The-Consolation-of-Exile.htm) in explaining that just as the theme of the haftara of this weeks parasha "Eikev" is "redemption", so too is the case with the parasha itself.

> Eikev is one of the “Seven [portions] of Consolation.” Since its Haftorah deals with redemption, we must accordingly say that the Torah portion does so as well.

Where does this idea come from that the theme of parashas Eikev has to do with redemption? Are there sources, besides the Rebbe's, that discuss this concept/principle?

Comment: I don't know about Eikev specifically, but the idea of connecting the theme of the haftara back to the parsha seems to be Rebbe's chiddush. A simple reading of the [Tur](https://www.sefaria.org/Tur%2C_Orach_Chaim.428.1) suggests they're not thematically related during this period, but in the Rebbe's view (supported by the [Shaloh](https://www.sefaria.org/Shenei_Luchot_HaBerit%2C_Torah_Shebikhtav%2C_Vayeshev%2C_Miketz%2C_Vayigash%2C_Introduction.2?lang=bi)) the timing is not coincidental, as discussed [here](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=16027&st=&pgnum=89&hilite=).

Comment: I am familair with that idea, especially with reading the parashiyos during the three weeks.